# How to convert a utf8 like string to a real utf8?

Tags: c#, json, encoding

I'm working on a client that should communicate with an MMO game server.
The client is using unity3d.
I get the data from the server with JSON format and I try to get the data in UTF8 encoding:

```
string responseString = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd()
JSONObject JOBJ = new JSONObject(responseString);
```

and what is inside the response string looks like:

```
"\u0645\u0639\u062f\u0646 \u062a\u06cc\u062a\u0627\u0646\u06cc\u0648\u0645"
```

Then I try to get the required utf8 string data out of the JSON:

```
string xy = JOBJ["name"].ToString();
byte[] utf = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xy);
string s2= System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf);
```

The Problem is when I Log the string:

```
Debug.Log("Jproperty :" + s2);
```

All I get is the \u secuences like this:

```
"\u0645\u0639\u062f\u0646 \u062a\u06cc\u062a\u0627\u0646\u06cc\u0648\u0645"
```

While if I put the same result in the xy in the first place I'll get the fine result.
Also I should mention that while I think that the s2.length should be 11 it is 66.

Any one can tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what you mean by "While if I put the same result in the xy in the first place I'll get the fine result."

Comment: I mean if i define string xy = "\u0645\u .... I can see the correct result in the debug.log.

Comment: Right. That means that something's encoding twice, or failing to decode. What does `responseString` look like? Please edit that into the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strings that contain unicode escape sequences are perfectly valid. Your data might be getting escaped before it is sent to the server.

Try [`Regex.Unescape`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape.aspx):

```
var nameEscaped = JOBJ["name"].ToString();
// nameEscaped =
// \u0645\u0639\u062f\u0646 \u062a\u06cc\u062a\u0627\u0646\u06cc\u0648\u0645

var name = Regex.Unescape(nameEscaped);
// name =
// معدن تیتانیوم
```